# Maven deploy plugin is asking for SCM details, what if I don't use one?

Tags: android, maven-2

I've followed the [instructions for configuring Maven](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Source?tm=4) for building android projects, this is what my POM looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenMess</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>Maven Android Plugin - samples</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <!--  platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6)-->
                        <platform>8</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <!--  the name of the avd device to use for starting the emulator-->
                        <avd>GoogleAPIs</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--  version 2.3 defaults to java 1.5, so no further configuration needed-->
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I can run `mvn install` ok, but when I run `mvn deploy` I get the following error

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to configure plugin parameters for: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4

check that the following section of the pom.xml is present and correct:

<distributionManagement>
  <!-- use the following if you're not using a snapshot version. -->
  <repository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <name>Repository Name</name>
    <url>scp://host/path/to/repo</url>
  </repository>
  <!-- use the following if you ARE using a snapshot version. -->
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <name>Repository Name</name>
    <url>scp://host/path/to/repo</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

Cause: Class 'org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository' cannot be instantiated
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Nov 14 18:56:41 GMT 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 58M/543M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What if I don't use a repository, how can I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `deploy` then you must provide a place to deploy to (a repository). The whole point of `deploy` is to upload your build to some server.

Use `package` if you just want to create an application package.

**Update:** Use `android:deploy` to deploy to the emulator or device.

Comment: what about deploying to an android emulator? That is what the maven-andorid plugin is trying to achieve

Comment: Then use `android:deploy`, not `deploy`. http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/plugin-info.html

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, if you just set up a dummy repository (e.g. valid `url` format, but invalid server or so), Maven will complain, but do its work.

Comment: I've tried that, it gives a different error then. ` Authentication failed: Cannot connect. Reason: java.net.UnknownHostException: host`

Comment: Then I don't remember correctly :) Did you try the local provider - http://maven.apache.org/scm/local.html? You can put some dummy folder (such as /tmp on Unix or c:/temp on Windows).

Comment: ... but I still think it can be somehow rectified by changing the connection. Try this: http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html - just change **both** the connection and developerConnection to something valid, except that the host name is bad. I had a similar issue recently and I think I solved it somehow along those lines, but I cannot recall all the details...

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a viable solution, as it still attempts to retrieve a previous version number from the SCM, and if you provide a dummy SCM it returns a connect exception :(

Comment: *sigh* Did you try local provider?